# Can android execute string as code?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, scripting

So basically I would like my app to read info from a database, this info would be a string that is valid java code. Once read, I would like my app to execute this string as if it were code. Is there any functionality packaged with the android sdk that supports this?

Essentially I want the phone to populate some data with information queried from a database. One of these pieces of information would be a statement like:

```
"return data.ZombieKillTotal >= 100000;"
```

Which would be used inside a statement like:

```
registerAchievement(new Achievement("Zombie Killer", new AchievementValidator() { 
    public boolean isSatisfied(Data data) { ExecStringAsCode(query result) } 
    });
```

I just don't know what to use for 'ExecStringAsCode' :(

Comment: Not really a good idea, it's even a terrible idea to execute string.

Comment: I don't know if you'd want to do this on Android or even if it's supported, but in Java you'd probably have to use dynamically compiled/loaded/executed classes.

Comment: @Colin: How would you recommend getting that information into the class from the database if not executing the string?

Comment: This is a really dangerous idea. Why not just parse the string and do what you need to do with it?

Comment: I am trying not to limit the functionality of the achievement validation. If I am misunderstanding perhaps you could provide an example of parsed string to code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the JRE library and imported `javax.script.*;`

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/

Answer (score 0):

The Java programming language doesn't really provide a feature for the execution of code in text strings.

You could embed an interpreter for a more script-friendly language (perhaps Python) and execute code that way.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute code loaded dynamicly you will have to use somthing like COdeDOM to create code and compile it then use reflection to load and excute it.